# Encoding error with sqlalchemy and postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, encoding, sqlalchemy

I'm using pyramid for a web application with a postgres database, wtforms, sqlalchemy and jinja2 and I'm having this error when the application try to get the issues types from database to fill a select field with wtforms:

```
Error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this is the issue types table into model.py:

```
class Mixin(object):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    created = Column(DateTime())
    modified = Column(DateTime())

    __table_args__ = {
        'mysql_engine': 'InnoDB',
        'mysql_charset': 'utf8'
    }
    __mapper_args__ = {'extension': BaseExtension()}

class IssueType(Mixin, Base):
    __tablename__ = "ma_issue_types"
    name = Column(Unicode(40), nullable=False)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
```

Into bd I have this:

```
# select name from ma_issue_types where id = 3;
name    
------------
Teléfono
```

this is the part where the error occurs

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from issuemall.models import DBSession, IssueType


class IssueTypeDao(object):

    def getAll(self):
        dbsession = DBSession()
        return dbsession.query(IssueType).all() #HERE THROWS THE ERROR
```

this is the Traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/issueMall/issuemall/controller/issueRegisterController.py", line 16, in issue_register
    form = IssueRegisterForm(request.POST)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 178, in __call__
    return type.__call__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 224, in __init__
    super(Form, self).__init__(self._unbound_fields, prefix=prefix)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 39, in __init__
    field = unbound_field.bind(form=self, name=name, prefix=prefix, translations=translations)
  File "/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 301, in bind
    return self.field_class(_form=form, _prefix=prefix, _name=name, _translations=translations, *self.args, **dict(self.kwargs, **kwargs))
  File "/issueMall/issuemall/form/generalForm.py", line 11, in __init__
    types = issueTypeDao.getAll()
  File "/issueMall/issuemall/dao/master/issueTypeDao.py", line 11, in getAll
    return self.__dbsession.query(IssueType).all()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2115, in all
    return list(self)
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2341, in instances
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3205, in fetchall
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchall_impl())
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3172, in _fetchall_impl
    return self.cursor.fetchall()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 5: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I try this, but it did not work
[ascii as default encoding in python](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/2609/ascii-as-default-encoding-in-python)

and I try something like this, but it did not work

[gae python ascii codec cant decode byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789770/gae-python-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte)

```
return dbsession.query(IssueType.id, IssueType.name.encode('utf-8')).all() #or decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of code. Could you try and localize your problem more, and edit our question to make it more tractable?

Comment: The error is here return dbsession.query(IssueType).all()

Comment: No, that's where the error manifests. I mean try to debug stuff to see what gets called in the end to see what is getting decoded using `ascii` and why?

Comment: just in this line the error manifiest return dbsession.query(IssueType).all() until that point the only thing that happens are called function without passing parameters, since it is obtained all records of the table

Comment: Somewhere before you use the `DBSession` it must have gotten a call like `DBSession.configure(bind=engine)` or something like this (unless I am confusing frameworks). Sure the `engine` has an `encoding='utf-8'` but could you please double check it does?

Comment: I used this DBSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))

Comment: Please include the *whole* traceback.

Comment: @MartijnPieters here is [traceback](http://pastebin.com/ZWkWHRNV)

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add that traceback there.

Comment: What database are you using? MySQL? This is the database client (*outside* of SQLAlchemy).

Comment: Ah, from an insert (now edited out) you inserted a byte string, not a unicode value. Insert `u'Teléfono'` instead of `'Teléfono'` perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters the database is postgres and when I do u'Teléfono' get this error [Traceback](http://pastebin.com/vEYb0RUn)

Comment: @jdurango: Why then does your code sample include `mysql_engine` and `mysql_charset`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Oh! I forgot to change that, initially was working with mysql and then I go to lock with postgres; I will remove that part to run it again to see what happens

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You need to configure Psycopg2's client encoding. See the [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#unicode):

> By default, the psycopg2 driver uses the `psycopg2.extensions.UNICODE` extension, such that the DBAPI receives and returns all strings as Python Unicode objects directly - SQLAlchemy passes these values through without change. Psycopg2 here will encode/decode string values based on the current “client encoding” setting; by default this is the value in the `postgresql.conf` file, which often defaults to `SQL_ASCII`. Typically, this can be changed to `utf-8`, as a more useful default:
>
> ```
> #client_encoding = sql_ascii # actually, defaults to database
>                              # encoding
> client_encoding = utf8
> ```
>
> A second way to affect the client encoding is to set it within Psycopg2 locally. SQLAlchemy will call psycopg2’s `set_client_encoding()` method (see: http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html#connection.set_client_encoding) on all new connections based on the value passed to `create_engine()` using the `client_encoding` parameter:
>
> ```
> engine = create_engine("postgresql://user:pass@host/dbname", client_encoding='utf8')
> ```
>
> This overrides the encoding specified in the Postgresql client configuration.

The `client_encoding` parameter can be specified as a query string in the engine URL:

```
 postgresql://user:pass@host/dbname?client_encoding=utf8
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the solution was change the encoding in the postgresql.conf

Comment: you can also set **postgresql://user:pass@host/dbname?client_encoding=utf8**

Answer (score 1):

I use mysql and set the charset like this. It works for me.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.engine.url import URL

db_url = {
    'database': 'db_name',
    'drivername': 'mysql',
    'username': 'username',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'host': '127.0.0.1',
    'query': {'charset': 'utf8'},
}

engine = create_engine(URL(**db_url), encoding="utf8")
```